# Not able to call second macro after first macro is generated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few subs that works perfectly fine individually. However when I put few subs together to be called in one sub, it won't run properly. After first sub is called and generated, the second sub won't run and came out an error. I just don't get it how it won't run, please anyone tell me where went wrong. I tried adjusting the codes but it won't work.

Mail merge won't work for my project as I have thousands of data to be generated. Thank you in advance.

This sub below is to call sub test1 and test2 and came out an error

```
Sub callsubs()
test1
test2
End Sub
```

[image]

Here is my sub test1 and test2 is the same as test1 so I won't be putting it again.

```
Option Explicit
Const FilePath As String = "Z:\PJ General\Staff\Admin Dept\Ching Lu\AP LOAN v3 Test\Correspondences\"
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Sub Copy2word(bookmarkName As String, Text2Type As String)

'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
wd.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=bookmarkName
wd.Selection.TypeText Text2Type

End Sub



Sub test1()

Dim doc As Object
Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim strName As String
strName = Sheet15.Range("C67")
wd.Visible = True

Dim dev_attn As String
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "Step 2a LBS-LPPSA.doc", ReadOnly:=True)
doc.Unprotect Password:="stwppj312"
With wd.ActiveDocument

dev_attn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry B").Range("C809").Value 

Copy2word "dev_attn", dev_attn

Call devref
Call stwpref

doc.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\" & "Step2a " & strName & ".doc"
End With
wd.Quit
Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, you create the Word application object several times - once via `Dim wd As New Word.Application` (early binding; the instance is assigned to the global variable `wd`), and every time you run `test1()` and `test2()` via `Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")` (late binding; the instance is assigned to the local variable `doc`). At the end of each `test1()` and `test2()` procedure, you destroy the global `wd` instance via `wd.Quit`. So by running `test1()` and `test2()` procedures sequentially, after the first one finishes, the `wd` object (which you access, for example in `wd.Visible = True`) will no longer be bound to the `Word.Application` instance, hence the error.
Creating multiple instances of "Word.Application" is time-consuming and resource-intensive, so I recommend creating such an object once and using it in all procedures, and removing it when done. Accordingly, don't create a local instance of "Word.Application" inside each of test1() and test2() procedures, but use only the global one.

```
Dim wd As New Word.Application
...
Sub callsubs()
    test1 ' without wd.Quit, without Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    test2 ' without wd.Quit, without Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wd.Quit
End Sub
```

In addition, the command `Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")` in your procedures creates a local instance of "Word.Application" that is not used at all, but wastes time and resources. This happens as follows:

```
Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application") ' a new instance of the "Word.Application" is created and bound with doc variable
...
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "Step 2a LBS-LPPSA.doc", ReadOnly:=True) ' doc variable re-binding with opened Document
...
'The "Word.Application" instance hasn't been destroyed, it still lives in memory (see Task Manager, section Background Processes)
```

I recommend you remove the line `Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")`

Comment: thank u!!! u manage to solve my problem! thank you very much!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is that you've created your wd object as a global variable that you then quit in Test1. This will cause Test2 to have no wd to reference.

I would bring the wd declaration into the Test1 and Test2 and then pass it to Copy2word as a parameter instead. Something like this:

```
    Sub Copy2word(bookmarkName As String, Text2Type As String, wd As Word.Application)
    [Same code]
    End Sub
    
    Sub test1()
    Dim wd As New Word.Application
    ...
    Copy2word "dev_attn", dev_attn, wd
    ...
    End Sub
```

Comment: hi @omega4096 thank you very much for helping, but manage to solve it now. thank you!!